# How to Implement an application with real time chat (audio,video,text,file support & tagging user in chat) system in dajngo

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to implement chatting application using django-channels,As I have to implement functionality in my app, such as file uploading, tagging user in chat.

I have tried to implement file uploading by calling api & upload the file to S3, then send the link to the socket.

Is there any another way to implement this scenario.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read [ask] and how to write a [mcve], as your question doesn't meet the requirements for being posted here. I wouldn't even know where to start to answer you.

Comment: I believe you can send a binary payload directly through the socket if you want but the approach you already implemented may be better